# ASP.NET Local IIS - sqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web

I created Web Api and I will use Local IIS.Then SQL Exception occurred.But when I started Web Api with IIS Express (http://localhost:4047), I can see true result in Postman.I don't understand reasons of this error.Because I tried 2 days ago with different ip address and everything was okay.I changed applicationHost.config

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:(ip address)" />
</bindings>
```

and I added this line in WebApplication1.csproj.cs,

```
 <IISUrl>http://(ip address)/api/Data/Post</IISUrl
```

Sorry for my English if I made mistakes.Thank you.

Comment: Please include your source code, and point us to the line throwing the exception. Also please include details of the exception being thrown - including the type and the stack trace.

Comment: Do you use a database of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express is started as a local process and it runs under your credentials.So you have accesss rights to connect to the database.But when you run in local IIS,it runs under the application pool identity and it cannot connect to the database.You have two options

1. Change the Local IIS website's [application pool identity to your account](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx)
2. Change the connection string to use sql account to connect and not a windows identity with (integratedSecurity=true) settings